# With LUA: How to I remove an item from a table?

Tags: lua

I can't seem to find a question quite like this.

I have a script that I've used to generate player names (for a game), it correctly stores names into a text file (players.txt) by appending the end of the file as they enter the game.  No sorting.  For instance:

```
Player1
Player4
Player3
Player2
```

How can I remove Player3 from the text file?

I do have a variable called currPlayers which is a table created from Players.txt that I want to use later on.  Should I search the table and have the whole file rewritten as players leave or just search the file itself? Not sure which would be better.

Comment: Having the whole file rewritten after the table changes seems fine if the table is small enough. But I have a question: Why does this file need to exist? If you add to it when a player joins and remove from it when they leave, why not just have a table? Is the file used elsewhere?

Comment: Actually, the text file probably doesn't have to exist, maybe I'm just using it for testing purposes.  The whole idea is this: I'm renaming players (on a gaming server) that enter, based on the contents of a text file.  I want to avoid the inadvertent assigning of duplicate concurrent player names, but when the player LEAVES, the name can be returned for use for another player entering.  I was under the impression a log file was required and that there may be no way to hold all of the names of the current players in a table, since the script runs, then closes.  That's why I use a text file.

Comment: If that's the case, you can just use Joseph Sible's option 1 given in the answer. You can do an equality check `if players['Name1'] then print("That name's taken")` to see if someone has that name, and Sible shows how to remove names from the list.

Answer (score 1):

There's two different ways that you could have the players in a table.

Option 1:

```
players = {Player1 = true, Player4 = true, Player3 = true, Player2 = true}
-- or equivalently
players['Player1'] = true
players['Player4'] = true
players['Player3'] = true
players['Player2'] = true
```

If that's how your table is set up, then just do `players['Player3'] = nil` to remove `Player3`.

Option 2:

```
players = {'Player1', 'Player4', 'Player3', 'Player2'}
-- or equivalently
players[1] = 'Player1'
players[2] = 'Player4'
players[3] = 'Player3'
players[4] = 'Player2'
```

If that's how your table is set up, then use an [`ipairs`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-ipairs) loop and [`table.remove`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.remove) to remove `Player3`, like this:

```
for k,v in ipairs(players) do
    if v == 'Player3' then
        table.remove(players, k)
        break
    end
end
```